# In Rails4 app, integrating Stripe, but Stripe says "Received unknown parameter: type"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

UPDATE:

Ah! This fixed it:

```
  stripe_account = Stripe::Account.create(
    {
      :legal_entity => { :type => "company" }, 
      :country => "US",
      :managed => true
    }
  )
```

In our Rails4 app we are trying to integrate Stripe. We are building an auction site, and we will use Stripe to both charge customers and then also send the money to the sellers.

We set up the pages that deal with charging, and everything works great on that side. Customers can make a purchase. We auth their cards, and then, when the seller delivers the product, we capture the charge. 100% perfection.

However, I have run into problems when I try to create the managed accounts for the sellers. This was working fine:

```
  stripe_account = Stripe::Account.create(
    {
      :country => "US",
      :managed => true
    }
  )
```

But the documentation says that I need to specify whether the seller is an individual or a company, so I did:

```
  stripe_account = Stripe::Account.create(
    {
      :type => "company", 
      :country => "US",
      :managed => true
    }
  )
```

And now I get this error:

```
 Stripe::InvalidRequestError in Supplier::ProfilesController#new
 Received unknown parameter: type
```

If I look here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account

I see:

```
 type
 string
 Either “individual” or “company”, for what kind of legal entity the account owner is for
```

So why is this an error?

UPDATE:

Ah! This fixed it:

```
  stripe_account = Stripe::Account.create(
    {
      :legal_entity => { :type => "company" }, 
      :country => "US",
      :managed => true
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! This fixed it:

```
 stripe_account = Stripe::Account.create(
   {
     :legal_entity => { :type => "company" }, 
     :country => "US",
     :managed => true
   }
 )
```

Comment: if this fixed it, please mark your answer as accepted. Otherwise, it'll keep showing up as an unanswered question that people need to devote attention to.